# Bootstrap Validation Groups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Does bootstrap have a validation group option like ASP.NET for validating forms on submission?

I have a page where I would like the user to either submit information on the main form or click another button and have a modal popup for the user to submit a secondary set of data. When I do this it tries to validate both sets of information but I only want it to validate the set of information that they have selected.

Below is an example of code showing this. The user should either send to an address or add a new address through the modal. Currently it validates all address fields but I only want the one on the main form or the one on the modal.

```
    <form>


<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="cbSaveAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Save Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="cbSaveAddress" type="checkbox" name="cbSaveAddress"/>                   
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-danger">&nbsp;</div>                      
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="txtAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input name="txtAddress" type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required="required" />       
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-danger">
            <span>*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Send"  id="btnSend" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" />      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
               <input type="button" name="btnAddNewAddress" value="Add New Address" id="btnAddNewAddress" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddAddress" /
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddAddress" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Address</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtAddAlias" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alias:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input name="txtAddAlias" type="text" id="txtAddAlias" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required="required" />       
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-danger">
                                <span>*</span>          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="txtAddAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input name="txtAddAddress" type="text" id="txtAddAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required="true" />       
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-danger">
                                <span>*</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ys4jq5r8/2/)

I have figured out if I create 2 forms (close the first form before the modal then open a second form around the modal) it works as I want it to. Unfortunately the wrapper I inherited makes this a bit challenging so I wanted to see if there was anything like validation groups where I can set which button a control is associated with.

[Example with multiple forms](https://jsfiddle.net/ys4jq5r8/3/)

Thanks